# Is Asynchronous URLFetch App Engine's fastest way to send real-time messages to external systems?

Tags: google-app-engine, udp, urlfetch

Is Asynchronous URLFetch the fastest mechanism to get out of the App Engine sandbox?

http://ikaisays.com/2010/06/29/using-asynchronous-urlfetch-on-java-app-engine/

We had experienced very slow URLFetches in the past, but think Pull Queues would introduce too much latency.

Our Google App Engine app needs to send UDP messages in near real-time.
Since App Engine supports only HTTP on port 80, we plan to use HTTP POST to EC2/Rackspace instances that in turn send the UDP message.

Comment: HTTP on port 80 restriction only applies for incoming requests, so outgoing request such as the one that you have could be directed at any external server port. How slow is your "very slow URL Fetches"? How much latency is acceptable for your near real-time communication?

Comment: We have not yet tested URLFetch speed in isolation; we had just noted that our URLFetch to things like Google Checkout APIs sometimes had 10 second latency (combo of URLFetch + Checkout).  Acceptable latency for this "near real-time" scenario is about 3 seconds.

Comment: If urlfetch is slow, it is almost certainly the server you are hitting, not the urlfetch infrastructure.  We don't support UDP so if you really need UDP, an external service is your only solution.  Over time we'll do something about this though.

Comment: FWIW, I use asynchronous URLFetch to send logging messages from my app to an external server, and based from experience the exhibited latency is very low, sub-500 ms on most cases. The [URLFetch system status page](http://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/urlfetch/2012/02/24#ae-trust-detail-urlfetch-external-aws-s3-latency) on fetches to external servers also shows the average latency to be ~100 ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the day, the time spent actually fetching the URL is the same whether you do it synchronously or asynchronously.

The difference lies in whether your app will need to wait for the result (and block until it comes), or whether it can fire off a request and then do other things while it's waiting. With asynchronous your app can fire off a request, and do other things [including firing off more requests] while it waits for the result to come back.

Comment: Have you tried testing whether GAE's setup for asynch or synch calls to URLFetch have any effect on speed of executing the actual HTTP post? We haven't yet, but were curious whether others have.

Comment: @CarterMaslan From a technical standpoint I cannot imagine why they would be different. Either way, the app instance should need to use the same internal APIs to communicate with URL fetch. And URL fetch should treat all requests the same. Never tested, but it would be mighty strange if it was implemented otherwise.